# Linux Shell - Delete a folder whose name startwith .git which is a part of inner folders

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, rm

here is a sample directory structure/tree

```
main_directory-|- folder1
               |- folder2
               |- folder3
               |- folder4 -|- .git
                           |- my_project
                           |- some_other_files
```

assume I'm in the main directory.

```
admin@admin:~/$ cd main_directory
admin@admin:~/main_directory$
```

here I want to execute some command which will delete all folders whose name starts with `.git` RECURSIVELY.

What I was trying =  `rm -r .git*`
its not working. or may be using someother command, e.g `mv` but I dont have any clue about that.

problem is I have many such folders and each of them has one or more `.git` so I cannot go manually in each directory and delete git folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find . -name .git -exec rm -r {} \;`

Comment: Uuups. Race condition? Sorry! :-)

Comment: I didn't understood the part after `rm -r` . what is `{} \;` ?

Comment: @micheal `find` syntax for the `-exec` argument. Read the man page.

Comment: Also, I always wrap this with quotes `find . -name .git -exec rm -r "{}" \;` if the filename has special characters it sometimes wont work

Comment: @stevo81989: Wrapping `{}` in quotes - `"{}"` - achieves nothing in terms of handling files with special characters. It only regulates how your shell will parse this particular command line. At least modern dash/bash/zsh parse `{}` without quotes literally, so it's not needed there. That would only make sense if you're using some more exotic shell.